# Wormeus and the Stickotaur (Maze 4)

Tags: mazes

Here is the fourth maze in the Wormeus series. The rules are explained in previous puzzles: [link](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/108070/wormeus-and-the-pink-lady-stickotaur), [link](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/109196/wormeus-and-the-stickotaur-maze-2), [link](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/109515/wormeus-and-the-stickotaur-maze-3).

This maze is based on one of the advanced levels in Theseus Plus for iOS (left image). Unfortunately, I had to change the starting position of both Wormeus and Stickotaur to make it work.

Your task is to eat all the apples in at most **159 moves**.

[image]

Comment: yay wormeus is back!

Comment: This is a tricky one! I have a feeling the very red apple at the nook of row 8, column 5 might actually be a herring..

Comment: @Bass what do you mean by herring? Do you have an almost-solution that eats every apple except r8c5 in 159 moves?

Comment: Damn it, I have a solution just short of 159 moves

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>Rant: At first I found a path that takes slightly more than 159 moves, couldn't for the life of me figure out how to optimize any further, got extremely frustrated, just to realize the next day that I forgot that the cells Wormeus and the lady stand on don't actually have an apple on them :) Major facepalm...</sub>

---

**158 moves**

GIF:

> [image]

Moves:

> `LDDeUReDeDeLeRDeReReReLUeUeReDeReUeDDeReUeReDeUUUDeDULeUeUeUeUeULReRLLeLeLeLeLeDeLeUeDRReReReReLDeLeLeLeLeDeRReReLDeLLeUDRDDDLeRRUeUeRUeReReRReUeLLeLeRUeRReUe`

Comment: Good job! My intended solution involves eating the upper left apples in a different order and somehow I needed an extra move. You got the main idea of eating the apple in r6c1 asap before it becomes a problem later (without this I believe it is impossible even with infinite number of moves)